# How to get appsetting from extension method

Tags: c#

currently I have a class and it sets redis expiration by default.

```
public static async Task SetRecordAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache,
    string recordId,
    T data,
    TimeSpan? absoluteExpireTime = null,
    TimeSpan? slidingExpireTime = null)
{
    var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions();

    options.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = absoluteExpireTime ?? TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.SlidingExpiration = slidingExpireTime;


    var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
    await cache.SetStringAsync(recordId, jsonData, options);
}
```

I would like to now set `options.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = Configuration["AppSettings:Expiration"]`

May I ask what's the best way to get a value from configuration to my class?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own service class :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public class MyService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        
        var mySetting = _configuration.GetValue<string>("MySettingKey"); // Access configuration values

  
    }
}
```

Register your service file in startup.cs :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Other service configurations...
        // AddScoped | AddSingleton | AddTransient any of these depending upon your case
        
        services.AddScoped<MyService>(); // Register your class with dependency injection

       
    }
}
```

Use it in controller like below :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyService _myService;

    public MyController(MyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _myService.SomeMethod();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't see how I can apply this to my extension class